# The Login Screen is not shown after applying patches

Tags: login

This morning (2016/02/23), I applied the latest patches for my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop (a virtual machine). Then I rebooted the system, but the login screen was not shown. I even didn't know that it was caused by latest patches until I applied the patches to another Ubuntu 14.04 desktop virtual machine - after showing the logo of ubuntu, it stuck there.

On the first Ubuntu VM which had SSH server installed before, I was able to log in to the system via SSH.

Could anyone help me with such a problem? I have several important services install in the second ubuntu VM and I need it urgently for my work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: log will be very helpful var/log/  var/log/messages